# r shinyapp: how can I print tables?

Tags: r, shinyapps

Sorry for this newbie-question but: can someone please tell me how I can print out a simple table() in a shiny app? I've tried different outputs (verbatimTextOutput(), tableOutput() ). Unfortunately, none of them worked so far.

```r
library(shiny)

# FAKE DATAFRAME
data <- reactive(  
                 data.frame(
                    group = sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                    var1 = round(runif(100, min = 0, max = 100), 0),
                    var2 = sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace = TRUE)
                  )
                )

# USER INTERFACE
ui <- fluidPage(
    tableOutput("table1")
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
            output$table1 <- renderTable({
                                          table(data()$group, data()$var2)
                                         })
}

# START APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This works on my Win 10 system

Comment: Same here, you might want to bring the reactive part into your server function to allow for reactivity once implemented

Comment: Yes, but the thing is it gives me the result in a "long" format. I'd rather have a crosstable as I get it when using `table()` normally.